# Is it possible that First and Second activity will not show again when clicked the button in third activity?

Tags: java, android-studio

Is it possible that First and Second activity will not show again when clicked the button in third activity?

Before I clicked the button in third activity, first and scond activity still can see and go back to previous.

Please can someone share code with me.?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you going to next activity add this in intent.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

also add finish();